# How can i make click between same class name, same name and same title on Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests

https://www.lcwaikiki.com/tr-TR/TR/kategori/erkek/tisort

On this page all products have same XPath and when I wanna click on product my test is fail.
**I don't wanna click specific item, I always wanna click to first product**.

I'm trying to click on with this code:

```
WebElement butttonToClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h5[@class='product-card__title']"));
butttonToClick.click();
```

I always change the XPath and also try to click on second or third item but it's not work. I'm newbie I couldn't find a solution for that thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

Use below XPath expression for first product:

```
(//h5[@class='product-card__title'])[1]
```

For second product:

```
(//h5[@class='product-card__title'])[2]
```

and so on..

**Working code for your reference:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.lcwaikiki.com/tr-TR/TR/kategori/erkek/tisort");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        
        // Accept cookies
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Tüm Çerezlere İzin Ver']"))).click();
        
        // Click on first product
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//h5[@class='product-card__title'])[1]"))).click();

}
```

Imports required:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this same issue. If you want to always click on the first product on the page, you can modify your code to **use the findElements method instead of findElement** and then select the first element from the list.

In below code, findElements returns a list of all elements matching the given XPath expression. Then, we check if the list is not empty to ensure that there is at least one product on the page. If there is a product, we select the first element from the list using get(0) and click on it.

```
List<WebElement> products = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h5[@class='product-card__title']"));
if (!products.isEmpty()) {
    WebElement buttonToClick = products.get(0);
    buttonToClick.click();
}
```